# Improve multiple merges of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes:

```
print(inventory_df)

dt_op        Prod_1  Prod_2 ... Prod_n
10/09/18       0        0         0
11/09/18       0        0         0
12/09/18       0        0         0

...

print(final_inspect)

    dt_op        Prod_1  
    10/09/18       10       
    11/09/18       2                
    12/09/18       5  

print(updated_df)
    dt_op        Prod_1  Prod_2 ... Prod_n
    10/09/18      10        0         0
    11/09/18       2        0         0
    12/09/18       5        0         0

    ...
```

I am trying to **update** the dataframe "*inventory_df*", with the values contained in "*final_inspect*", in order to get "**updated_df**" with:

```
final_inspect = pd.DataFrame(data = {'dt_op': inspect["dt_op"] , j: inventory}) 
final_inspect_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'dt_op':inventory_df.dt_op }) 

final_inspect_1 = final_inspect_1.merge(final_inspect, on = "dt_op", how = "left").fillna(0)
inventory_df = inventory_df.merge(final_inspect_1, on = ["dt_op", j], how = "outer").fillna(0)

inventory_df = inventory_df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)
```

The solution is cumbersome, but the **update** **function** from pandas does **not** seem to work ( inventory_df.update(final_inspect) ).

How can I improve this solution, in order to run it on several (3000) items?

N.B. The **size** of **updated_df** has to be the **same** as **inventory_df**, and nrows of final_inspect are less than nrows of inventory_df.

Comment: Can you further explain what does not work with `update()`? For me, it works with the data you provided. The only thing `update()` may do is to change the dtype from int to float (which is possibly related to [this known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4094). However, you could fix this by using `inventory_df.update(final_inspect).astype(int)`.

Comment: running the code you suggester raises: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype' @normanius

Comment: My bad, `update()` operates in-place and returns None. Sorry. I meant the following: `inventory_df.update(final_inspect); inventory_df = inventory_df.astype(int)`. Obviously, the latter works only if the dataframe consists of values that can be converted to int.

Comment: What exactly does not work with `update()`?

Comment: It does not update the first dataframe, leaving zeros. Unfortunately, I have a datetime object that, if converted to int, becomes a long set of numbers. Furthermore, even trying to convert only the product column to int update does not work.

Comment: Ah, this was not clear from your problem description. It's a possible reason for your problem. Anyways, it would be helpful if you had posted a minimal reproducing example...

Comment: `update()` aligns on indices, so both left and right dataframe (or series) must have an index which permits a matching of the entries. Have you checked the indices? `print(final_inspect.index)`, `print(inventory_df.index)`

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you for your feedback @normanius